# Zero-inflated negative binomial model for true zeros

Tags: r, modeling, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

The `zeroinfl` function in the `pscl` package in R assumes that zeros include both false zeros and true zeros. I have a zero inflated dataset that I'm confident only includes true zeros. Is it appropriate to use `zeroinfl` function on this dataset? Or would the `hurdle` function be more appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

In such situations the hurdle() model is usually easier to interpret. Hence I would recommend using that.

However, the difference between zeroinfl() and hurdle() models is often not very large. So typically I recommend to use the model that is easier to interpret for a given data set/application.